# Decompressing a vector into another vector using miniz in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, miniz

I'm trying to do the simplest thing here. I want to create a method that will take in a byte (char) array, inflate it using miniz `tinfl_decompress` method and then return a byte array containing the inflated data.

First things first. The arrays given will never be bigger than 100kB, vast majority will be smaller than 50k. Hence, I don't think I need to use any kind of buffer for it. Anyway, this is what I've got:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> unzip(std::vector<unsigned char> data)
{
    unsigned char *outBuffer = new unsigned char[1024 * 1024];

    tinfl_decompressor inflator;
    tinfl_status status;
    tinfl_init(&inflator);

    size_t inBytes = data.size() - 9;
    size_t outBytes = 1024 * 1024;

    status = tinfl_decompress(&inflator, (const mz_uint8 *)&data[9], &inBytes, outBuffer, (mz_uint8 *)outBuffer, &outBytes, 0);

    return ???
}
```

I know the output I want begins at memory location `&outBuffer`, but I don't know how long it is (I do happen to know it will be less than 1MB), so I cannot pack it into a vector and send it on it's way. I had hoped that `outBytes` would hold the size of the output, but they are set to 1 after the decompression. I know that decompression didn't fail, since `status` returned is `TINFL_STATUS_DONE (0)`.

Is this even the right way of doing it? This is a method that will be called a lot in my program, so I want something that is as fast as possible.

How do I get the vector out of it? Should I use a different data type? An array (the [] type)? The decompressed data will be read sequentially only once, after what it will be discarded.

**EDIT:**

**It seems that the file I was trying to decompress was not of the proper format; it was zip, this takes zlib.**

Comment: Why don't you use `tinfl_decompress_mem_to_mem()`? You should take your input as `std::vector<unsigned char> const &data`. Once you figure out the size of the expanded data, you can `return std::vector<unsigned char>(outBuffer, outBuffer + length)`

Comment: That's why I asked. But how do I figure out the size of the decompressed data?

Comment: You tell it the address of the size of your output buffer and it modifies that value.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: Totally untested code.

It should go something like exchange

```
unsigned char *outBuffer = new unsigned char[1024 * 1024];
```

for

```
std::vector<unsigned char> outBuffer(1024 * 1024);
```

to get a vector. Then call `tinfl_decompress` using the `data` method to get the vector's underlying buffer. It should look something like

```
status = tinfl_decompress(&inflator, 
                          (const mz_uint8 *)&data[9], 
                          &inBytes, 
                          (mz_uint8 *)outBuffer.data(), 
                          (mz_uint8 *)outBuffer.data(), 
                          &outBytes, 
                          0);
```

And then `resize` the vector to the number of bytes stored in the vector for convenience later.

```
outBuffer.resize(outBytes);
```

Note the vector will NOT be resized down. It will still have a capacity of 1 MiB. If this is a problem, an additional [call to `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` is required](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit).

Finally

```
return outBuffer;
```

Comment: I'm not getting valid output. Will this work for data compressed using SharpZipLib? Are those the same algorithms that are used?

Comment: Couldn't tell you, but if both are following the ZIP specification, both should read each other's files. First confirm that an off-the-shelf utility can read the file. All I did here was apply a generic method for reading an unknown amount of data directly into a vector.

Comment: Okay, Windows 10 doesn't seem to have any problems reading the file, however, the miniz seems to fail when reading it. Any ideas what might be the culprit?

Comment: It's the line 1464 in miniz.c that messes it up: `if ((counter = (r->m_raw_header[0] | (r->m_raw_header[1] << 8))) != (mz_uint)(0xFFFF ^ (r->m_raw_header[2] | (r->m_raw_header[3] << 8)))) { TINFL_CR_RETURN_FOREVER(39, TINFL_STATUS_FAILED); }`